# change text in text file in particular manner

Tags: python, file

I have a text file and there are some lines called

```
moves={123:abc:567:mno}
```

No I want to convert it in the form

```
moves={123:abc, 567:mno}
```

i.e. i want to replace : with , when ':' is after a string and behind a number i.e i want to make it like in a python dictionary format i know how i can change a particular line in the text file like

```
with open("images/filename.txt", 'r+', encoding='Latin1') as fp:
    # read an store all lines into list
    lines = fp.readlines()
    # move file pointer to the beginning of a file
    fp.seek(0)
    # truncate the file
    fp.truncate()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('moves='):
            do something()
    fp.writelines(lines)
```

I am not being able to figure out how should i replace the line and make it in my desired why. Please don't delete or close the question tell me how i should edit the questionin the comments so i can change it instead.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = 'moves={123:abc:567:mno}'
t = s.split(':')
print(t[2:5])
# print(':'.join(t[:2])+','+':'.join(t[2:]))
output = ''
for i in range(int(len(t)/2)):
    output += ':'.join(t[i*2:i*2 + 2]) + ', '
output = output.removesuffix(', ')
print(output)
```

Thanks @Lancelot du Lac to help me improvising your answer I have got the answer to my question

Answer (score 1):

If you have a line in your file (as a string) and it's exactly in that format then you can split the string on the colon separators then re-join with a comma in the appropriate place. For example:

```
s = 'moves={123:abc:567:mno}'
t = s.split(':')
print(':'.join(t[:2])+','+':'.join(t[2:]))
```

**Output:**

```
moves={123:abc,567:mno}
```

Comment: I don't always have only two items it is sometimes like moves={123:abc:567:mno:789:xyz} and sometimes it has only two things it can vary 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. items

Comment: @ROOPAMBER You should edit your question clarify the problem